# Limiting Jenkins pipeline to running only on specific nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building jobs that will be using Jenkins piplines extensively. Our nodes are designated per project by their tags, but unlike regular jobs the pipeline build does not seem to have  the "Restrict where this project can be run" checkbox. How can I specify on which node the pipeline will run the way I do for regular jobs?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am setting up multibranch pipeline and would like to restrict the build on specific slave, thanks

Answer (score 58):

You specify the desired node or tag when you do the `node` step (in a scripted pipeline):

```
node('specialSlave') {
   // Will run on the slave with name or tag specialSlave
}
```

See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node for an extended explanation of the arguments to `node`.

**Edit 2019:** This answer (and question) was made back in 2017, back then there only was one flavor of Jenkins pipeline, scripted pipeline, since then declarative pipeline has been added. So above answer is true for scripted pipeline, for answers regarding declarative pipeline please see other answers below.

Comment: This answer is the only one worked. I tried this: { node { label 'labelName' } }, but not work.

Answer (score 55):

Choosing a node for the entire pipeline which has the label `X` in a [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) with json format:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'X' }
...
...
}
```

You can chose agent on the stage level too, and run different stages on different agents:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    ...
    ...
    stages {
        stage("One"){
            agent { label 'X' }
            ...
            ...
        }
        stage("Two"){
            agent { label 'Y' }
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You also can apply multiple labels with **or** (`||`) or with **and** (`&&`) operator.

Running the job on any of the nodes which has label `X` **or** label `Y`:

```
agent { label 'X || Y' }
```

Running the job only on nodes which have **both** label:

```
agent { label 'X && Y' }
```

More in the [Jenkins Pipeline reference guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-parameters).

ps: if you are reading this you probably have just started using Jenkins pipeline and you are not sure if you should use declarative or scripted pipeline. Short answer: it's better to start with declarative. From [jenkins.io](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#declarative-versus-scripted-pipeline-syntax):

> Declarative and Scripted Pipelines are constructed fundamentally
> differently. Declarative Pipeline is a more recent feature of Jenkins
> Pipeline which:
>
> - provides richer syntactical features over Scripted Pipeline syntax, and
> - is designed to make writing and reading Pipeline code easier.

Comment: And if you want to run on a node with one of several labels: "agent { label 'X||Y' }"

Comment: @nsantos it keeps surprising me how bad Jenkins docs are. It doesn't mention that several labels thing in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: @nsantos any idea how to do `label.startswith 'Prefix'`?

Comment: Thx @nsantos, I've included that too.

Answer (score 30):

To be clear, because Pipeline has two Syntax, there are two ways to achieve that.

### Declarative

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent { label 'slave-node​' }
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
                sh '''
                '''
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            echo 'This will run only if successful'
        }
    }
}
```

### Scripted

```
node('your-node') {
  try {

    stage 'Build'
    node('build-run-on-this-node') {
        sh ""
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agent or Node where we should not execute the jenkins job :

- This is the negation of the problem statment i.e. node where not to run
- It was most weird solution to me but issue has been already raised to [jenkins community](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-31369)

> agent { label '!build-agent-name' }

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run entire jenkins pipeline to run on single node, use the following format

```
pipeline {
agent { 
    label 'test1' 
    
}

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Building..'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            echo 'Testing..'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying....'
        }
    }
}
```

}

if you need to execute each stage in different nodes, use the below format,

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Building..'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            node("test1"){
            echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying....'
        }
    }
}
```

}