# Why pipeline jobs appear on built-in node even if "number of executor" is zero

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I've configured jenkins with kubernetes as the cloud provider, and pipeline jobs are executed in pods defined by pod-template. But the built-in node is acting like a postman who takes all pipeline jobs and deliver them onto newly created pods, and "number of executor" on built-in node is zero.

**Pipeline jobs appear on built-in node for a few hundred milliseconds**

[built-in node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsVbR.png)

**Pipeline jobs are delivered onto new pods**

[new pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNXm9.png)

**Pipeline script**

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      cloud 'xx-center'
      yaml """
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: jnlp
            image: xxxx
          - name: build
            image: yyyy
      """
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage("build") {
      steps {
        buildName "xx-center-01"
        container("build") {
           script {
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Related reading:

[Jenkins pipeline job always tries to start on master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48344432/jenkins-pipeline-job-always-tries-to-start-on-master)

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-31866

Why pipeline jobs appear on built-in node even if "number of executor" is zero